# How to only read data from a socket when necessary

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am communicating with a piece of hardware that has only a rudimentary API that supports basic API calls.

Unfortunately some of the API calls illicit a response, and some do not.  I want to read the response when there is one, or just do nothing when there is not.

Here is the code I have been using:

```
def send_message(self, message, host):
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect((host, self.PORT))
        s.send(bytes(message, 'ascii'))
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print(data)
```

Unfortunately this binds the entire process when there is not data received.  I only want to read data when there is an actual response. Is there a way to do this with the Python standard library?

Comment: might depend on your OS, but perhaps the `select` module will work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, if you have control over the target API, I would suggest implementing a reply for every message. A reply ACK (acknowledge) for every message sent would make your API more robust, and sidestep this issue entirely.

If that's not an option, then I would create classes for the different types of messages:

```
class Message(object):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg

class MessageWReply(Message):
    await_reply = True

class MessageNoReply(Message):
    await_reply = False
```

Create all of your message classes, then use them like this:

```
def send_message(self, message, host):
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect((host, self.PORT))
        s.send(bytes(message, 'ascii'))

        if message.await_reply:
            data = s.recv(1024)
            print(data)
```

Alternatively, if you don't want the overhead of creating all of the classes, you could use a dictionary to map the messages to the correct action:

```
messages = {
    'message with reply 1': True, # wait for reply
    'message with reply 2': True,
    'message with reply 2': True,
    'message without reply 1': False, # don't wait for reply
    'message without reply 2': False
}
```

Then do this:

```
def send_message(self, message, host):
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect((host, self.PORT))
        s.send(bytes(message, 'ascii'))

        if messages[message]:
            data = s.recv(1024)
            print(data)
```

The second method has cleaner initialization (less boilerplate code), but is a bit less clear. For someone not familiar with the code, it's not clear what the value stored at `messages[message]` actually means, while `message.await_reply` is crystal clear. Something like [named tuples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) may be a good compromise - you can initialize everything in one data structure while still using named fields for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know if the response is supposed to follow a priori to sending the message then you are doomed. Let me repeat: if the API either responds or not and you don't know when then it's game over. That's because the question "should I wait for the response?" is unanswerable. And it is unrelated to Python at all, switching language won't help solving that. But such API would be extremely bad. Many useful tools (e.g. timeouts, concurrent access) would be impossible (or extremely hard) to implement.

On the other hand if you do know when the API is supposed to respond and when it is not then it is as simple as creating two functions: one with `recv` and one without. And use them appropriately. So the main work you have to do is to distinguish between notifications (that do not require response) and requests (that do require response). And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with similar programs, and in one I used `if message`, `message` in this case being a string received from the socket. Here's my code:

```
while True:
readbuffer = readbuffer + s.recv(1024)
temp = string.split(readbuffer, "\n")
readbuffer = temp.pop()

for line in temp:
    try:
        user = getUser(line)
        message = getMessage(line)
    except IndexError:
        print "Nothing to receive from the server!"

    if message:
        #responses here
```